# How to set date with Epoch format

Tags: date

I want to set date from a seconds since epoch value, for instance I want to set date with input value `1452053571`.

I read through `date -help` but not found anything.

Is there any parameters to do it?

Comment: You did not read carefully, try `date --date='@2147483647'`

Comment: @cuonglm Thank you, I mean `How to set` ?

Comment: Ok, `sudo date -s "$(date --date='@2147483647')"` :)

Comment: Just simple, `date -s '@2147483647'`. Please reword+reformat your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @cuonglm Post an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With [GNU date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation), you can use the same date string format for both `-d` and `-s` options.

To convert from seconds since epoch to human readable format:

```
date -d '@2147483647'
```

To set it:

```
date -s '@2147483647'
```

---

With *BSD `date`:

```
# Convert seconds since epoch
$ date -r 2147483647 
Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 UTC 2038

# Set date by seconds since epoch
$ date "$(date -r 2147483647 +'%y%m%d%H%M.%S')"
Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 UTC 2038
```

Comment: Such a strange thing that BSD does not simply allow to use Epoch as direct input.